# How to access JSON object value

Tags: arrays, json, perl, object

i have this `print STDERR Dumper $data`:
`$VAR1 = '{

    "url_date":null,

    "footer":null,"id":"18",

    "authors":[

            {"initials":"B.","last_name":"Best","has":0,"id":12},

            {"initials":"D.","last_name":"Dough","has":1,"id":10},

            {"initials":"F.","last_name":"Fuss","has":0,"id":15,}

          ],

    "url_headline":null,

    "headline":"test"}';`
 i would like to to access **Dough** how would i do that?
i tried `print STDERR Dumper $data.authors[1].last_name` but got syntax error.

2nd try
`use JSON::XS qw( decode_json );

 my $coder = JSON::XS->new->utf8->pretty->allow_nonref;

 my $p = $coder->decode ($.data);`

Answer (score 4):

You have a string. What the string contains is valid JSON and valid YAML. You need to parse the JSON, and the best way to do that is with an existing parser like [JSON::XS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?JSON%3a%3aXS).

```
use JSON::XS qw( decode_json );
my $data = decode_json($data_json);
$data->{authors}[1]{last_name}
```

Comment: i have a syntax error... i updated the code see 2nd try. `print STDERR Dumper %{$p};` gave me the whole $data info but when i do `print STDERR Dumper %{$p}->authors[1]{last_name};` i have a syntax error too..

Comment: That's cause you didn't use what I posted.

Comment: i did tried what you posted and got `syntax error at  line 78, near "->authors["` then i when to the JSON::XS page and found the 2nd try and have a syntax error too.. what is the problem?

Comment: $p->{authors}[1]{last_name}  not %{$p}->authors[1]{last_name}.   Looks like you're trying to call a method on a what ends up being a string. %{$p} with stringify the hashref and then you're trying to call a method on that. You just need to dereference that hashref like $p->{account}.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to decode string to Perl hash reference first with [`JSON`](http://p3rl.org/JSON) module and then use regular Perl's hash access syntax `$data->{"authors"}[1]{"last_name"}`.